# Can a client authenticate multiple Nginx Servers using one single generic certificate?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, openresty, self-signed-certificate

I am having an nginx docker with which I would be spinning up multiple servers on different IP's . But the targeted clients to make call to this server would be just two always. I am trying out SSL to enable the security for my server.

For trying SSL locally. I created a self signed certificate with my local IP 127.0.0.1 and configured that in my nginx.config. I used the generated certificate in my python request to my server as below and i was able to get right response.

```
resp = requests.get(uri, verify='newserv.crt')
```

I generated key using the commands as below

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout newserv.key -out newserv.crt -config ssl_config.cnf
```

ssl_config content looks like below

```
[req]
default_bits  = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = XX
stateOrProvinceName = N/A
localityName = N/A
organizationName = NginxProxy
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

I am having a script with in nginx to update the ssl_config for each IP that it gets hosted so then SSL_config would look like below

```
[req]
    default_bits  = 2048
    distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
    req_extensions = req_ext
    x509_extensions = v3_req
    prompt = no
    [req_distinguished_name]
    countryName = XX
    stateOrProvinceName = N/A
    localityName = N/A
    organizationName = NginxProxy
    [req_ext]
    subjectAltName = @alt_names
    [v3_req]
    subjectAltName = @alt_names
    [alt_names]
    IP.1 = "hostedIP"
```

and the script would handle generating certificate with the latest ssl_config

Is there a way I could have the client authenticate all these servers using one genertic certificate. such that i dont need to make any change on client side everytime when i have new server deployed with the new IP.

Comment: TLS certificates have nothing to do with IP address. They prove DNS name, not IP

Comment: @Konrads You are wrong. Take a look at [this](https://1.1.1.1/) server certificate for example.

Comment: @IvanShatsky i stand corrected; however - my statement is true in the general case, no CA* will issue you a cert for IP address, because IP address ownership is impossible to reliably validate. Cloudflare gets around this by being a sub-CA with own rules.